# Compilation fails for Generic class with Generic Interface

Tags: java, generics

To my understanding following code should run without any compilation error.

However, when I run this program I am getting following compilation error.

> The member type B.D cannot be qualified with a parameterized type,
>   since it is static. Remove arguments from qualifying type B

```
class B<X> {
    interface C {
    }

    interface D<Y> {
    }
}

class Test {
     // compilation fails here
    B<String>.D<String>[] arr = new B<String>.D<String>[10];
}
```

Please help me understand this behavior.

Comment: For the record: I removed the first class A from your example - as that class doesn't contribute to the overall problem. So I found it to be rather confusing.

Comment: @GhostCat- Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a way similar to an inner `static` class, a nested interface does not have an association to an instance of its outer class, only to the class itself. All `static` members are shared among all instances of `B`, regardless of `B`'s type parameter. Consider:

```
class B<T> {
    public static int shared = 0;
}
```

Variable `shared` is the same in `B<String>`, `B<Integer>`, `B<Object>` and so on. An attempt to access it on a parameterized `B` leads to a compile error:

```
int copy = B<String>.shared; // <<== Does not compile
```

Hence, type parameter of `B` has no effect on the declaration of `arr`, so Java wants you to remove it:

```
B.D<String>[] arr = new B.D[10];
```

Comment: @GhostCat I didn't study *your* edits, I recalled that most of *my* edits were like that. Plus, of course, the formatting, which I often do in order to be able to read the question myself ;-)

Comment: Beyond that: see you 7 to 10 weeks ... legendary up next ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can **not** create arrays of concrete parametrized types. Example:

```
Pair<Integer,Integer>[] intPairArr = new Pair<Integer,Integer>[10]; // illegal
```

does not work. See [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104) for details.

But it looks like the compiler is giving you a different, less helpful error message here because it *first* stumbles over the fact that *nested* interfaces are similar to *static* inner classes.

So, the only thing that you can do is: **ignore** the generic type on the rhs of the assignment:

```
B.D<String>[] arr = new B.D[10];
```

which of course leads to type safety warnings - and makes the whole idea of having that inner interface being generic somehow obsolete.

So the real answer is probably: generics and arrays do not go well together in Java - avoid using them in the first place. And don't be surprised that making things *more complicated* by bringing in interface nesting results in even less of "nice user experience".

Answer (score 1):

Inner interfaces are always `static` (unlike classes). So parameter `String` for B make no sense in definition `new B<String>.D<String>`.